# how do i print my form?

Tags: vb.net

I need to print an image of my VB.Net `Windows.Form` when the user clicks a button. Is there a good method for doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `PrintForm` component.  Please see [How to: Print a Form by Using the PrintForm Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629268.aspx):

> The PrintForm component enables you to
>   quickly print an image of a form
>   exactly as it appears on screen
>   without using a PrintDocument
>   component. The following procedures
>   show how to print a form to a printer,
>   to a print preview window, and to an
>   Encapsulated PostScript file.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to amend the image the following code will capture the bitmap and send it to the printer (On the Button1 Click)

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Form1

Dim WithEvents mPrintDocument As New PrintDocument
Dim mPrintBitMap As Bitmap


Private Sub m_PrintDocument_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles mPrintDocument.PrintPage
    ' Draw the image centered.
    Dim lWidth As Integer = e.MarginBounds.X + (e.MarginBounds.Width - mPrintBitMap.Width) \ 2
    Dim lHeight As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Y + (e.MarginBounds.Height - mPrintBitMap.Height) \ 2
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(mPrintBitMap, lWidth, lheight)

    ' There's only one page.
    e.HasMorePages = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Copy the form's image into a bitmap.
    mPrintBitMap = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Width)
    Dim lRect As System.Drawing.Rectangle
    lRect.Width = Me.Width
    lRect.Height = Me.Width
    Me.DrawToBitmap(mPrintBitMap, lRect)


    ' Make a PrintDocument and print.
    mPrintDocument = New PrintDocument
    mPrintDocument.Print()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't take into account the paper size.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a snapshot of the form, you'll have to simulate a screen capture. Here's a [sample](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=385497) that'll help. It's going to be pretty ugly though, so you may want to consider making it a report using a PDF or report builder.

Comment: Huh, had no idea. Cool, tnx. :)