# VB.Net. Print Tab Page on Form using a button

Tags: vb.net

I have a button called 'Print' on one of my Tab Pages.
How do add a print command to this button that allows the user to print the content of the Tab Page?

Rico

Answer (score 0):

> Modify your question to make it more clearer. See
>   [how do i print my form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966596/how-do-i-print-my-form)