# There is part of my form not appear in print

Tags: vb.net

I want to print my form (all controls except `Button` controls).

But there is a part of my form that does not appear when I print it .
How to make all of my form appear on the paper?

Here is my code:

```
 Try
        Dim ctl As Control
        For Each ctl In Me.Controls
            If ctl.GetType.FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.Button" Then
                ctl.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
        'Before printing, set Form.BackColor as White
        Dim FormBackColor As Color = Me.BackColor
        Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.Refresh()
        'Printing the form
        Dim PF As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm
        PF.PrintAction = PrintAction.PrintToPreview
        PF.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.Scrollable)
        'After printing, restore settings
        For Each ctl In Me.Controls
            If ctl.GetType.FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.Button" Then
                ctl.Visible = True
            End If
        Next
        Me.BackColor = FormBackColor

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: are you trying to print a picture of the form without the buttons? And which part of the form does not appear???

Comment: yes i'm trying to do this thing

Comment: WHICH part of the form doesnt appear?  Whats the problem???  IF the form is too large to fit on a page, you could capture the screen to a bitmap, scale it to fit on a page and print that.  Or you might just need to change the page orientation.  Hard to tell.

Comment: the right part does not appear and how can i change it to bitmap ????  please write code

Comment: is the page printing in Portrait or Landscape? if you just need to turn the page sideways to fit, `VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Printer` probably has a property for that (there is in `VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Compatibility.VB6 Namespace`).  I know it has SCALE methods you can use to "squeeze" the image onto the page.  Try that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i print my form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966596/how-do-i-print-my-form)