# printing and saving current record

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports, save, addition

hello everyone i have Form1 and Form2 for crystal report viewer , the Form1 as main data entry and main page has 10 fields of TextBox and 1 datagridview
i want to combine save then print directly THE selected current Records but i failed i tried many ways and i changed and edited codes but no luck.. the only things i got that i was able to print in crystal reports viewer but for the whole thing not the current selected record my code of printing is

```
 Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
 Imports System.Data
 Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
 Public Class Form1
 Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=sh;password=***;database=saj;sslMode=none")
 Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("", conn)
 Dim dt As New DataTable
 Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
 Dim bs As New BindingSource
 Dim sex As String
 Dim ds As DataSet
 Dim myReport As New ReportDocument

    Private Sub pr_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pr.Click
    Dim rep As New CrystalReport1
    rep.SetDataSource(dt)
    Form2.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "\CrystalReport1.rpt"
    Form2.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    Form2.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    Form2.Show()
```

i also tried to fillert datagridview as the code below

```
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Text) Then
        bs.Filter = String.Format("r Like '%{0}%'", r.Text)

    Else


        Dim rep As New CrystalReport1
        Dim DataViewFilter As New DataView(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DataViewFilter
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DataViewFilter
        bs.Filter = String.Format("r Like '%{0}%'", r.Text)
        rep.SetDataSource(dt)
        Form2.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "\CrystalReport1.rpt"
        Form2.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        Form2.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    End If
    Form2.Show()
```

but did not work :( .. any help please

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Just to get a better idea of the problem, instead of just printing from a Crystal Report, you also want to print the originally selected record?

Comment: thank you..yes  i need to print the selected record for example in the 10 fields of TextBoxs there will be First Name and Second Name and Last Name,,,,,and other Data too i want to press add or save button but same time it will print that selected shown data

Comment: What have you found out so far, is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015287/how-to-print-datagridview-table-with-its-header-in-vb-net) similar to what you'd need?  Or another example, [this will print anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966596/how-do-i-print-my-form)